# how to calculate sum of an average field in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-xi

I have a field that calculates an average per row (Avg_Amt), it gives a correct output. My problem is how can I calculate the total summary of the average field (Avg Amt) then place it to the report footer.

Thanks & Best Regards.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more.. on where did you place the `avg` in your report

Answer (score 0):

Create 2 formula fields one for average and one for sum and insert this formula the first one

```
 formula = Average ({Feild Name})
```

in the second formula from the report fields drag and drop the average formula and add the sum operation like :

```
 formula = SUM({@Average})
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is a straight average, use the sum wizard to add a sum for each field, then insert a formula field see below, this will actually get you to the accurate basis points average

```
(Sum ({@Field_1})/Sum ({@Field_2}))*100
```